# IBM WebSpshere Portal

Tags: websphere-portal

I have read many resources about theme customization on IBM WebSpherePortal 8, but none of them was helpful in practice. I need to create metro design like on Windows 8 for the WebSpherePortal. Having found ready to use template of metro style, how can I apply it to the WebSpherePortal 8?
I definitely know that I need to generate single ear file with RAD which includes all dynamic and static files, but the templates I found do not include dynamic parts. I am a bit lost in materials I have read. Can anyone explain me how to create design for the portal?

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating a new static theme based on the theme that shipped with Portal 8. Apply your new html markup to the theme_en.html or any other language your website support. you should also create a copy of your dynamic theme and apply any html changes you need to your dynamic content. Once done, all you need to do is register your static and dynamic theme.

Comment: Do you have tutorials from what I can implement you suggestion?